# Extra Arguments in position

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, swift5

I have an array of usernames and passwords as dictated by line 18 and 19. At line 36, is there a way where I can include the entire array of passwords (such as username (0), (1) and (2)) rather than have to duplicate the code over and over again?

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtUserName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!

let usernames = ["usernames1","usernames2","usernames3"]
let passwords = ["password1","password2","password3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view1.layer.cornerRadius = 12.5
    view2.layer.cornerRadius = 12.5

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ISUSERLOGGEDIN") == true {
        let HomeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(HomeVC, animated: false)
    }
}


@IBAction func authenticateUser(_ sender: Any) {
    if txtUserName.text == usernames[0,1,2] && txtPassword.text == passwords[0,1,2] {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ISUSERLOGGEDIN")
                    let HomeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeVC
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(HomeVC, animated: true)
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Correct!", message: "You are now logged in", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        }
    if (txtUserName.text!.count) < 6 || (txtPassword.text!.count) < 6 {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Whoops",
                                      message: "Please enter all information to log in.",
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Dismiss",
                                      style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can also make a dictionary out of those two arrays and have something like this: dictionary.allKeys.contains(“text”)

Comment: How would I implement a dictionary? Would this replace my 'let usernames = [""]'?

Answer (score 0):

If user can login with **any** username and any password from list (for example **first username and third password**), you can user code like this

```
if usernames.contains(txtUserName.text ?? "") && passwords.contains(txtPassword.text ?? "") {
```

---

If it should be pairs like (only **first username with first password** or **second username with second password**), the simplest code will be

```
if let userNameIndex = usernames.firstIndex(of: txtUserName.text ?? ""),
   let passwordIndex = passwords.firstIndex(of: txtPassword.text ?? ""),
   userNameIndex == passwordIndex {
          UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ISUSERLOGGEDIN")
          ...
```

Comment: This does work, however now it logs in the user even when the user has not entered a username or password, or when the user has entered an incorrect username and password! Any ideas to resolve this?

Comment: @HenryHall Indeed, you should also check that index of username and password is not nil, I've edited my original answer, now it should work.

Comment: @HenryHall happy to hear it. Please mark my answer as correct, if it fixed your issue.